# Equation T(v) = Av not satisfied for the matrix of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In the following image, we compute the matrix of a linear map/transformation, and we get the matrix A as

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
121 & 201\\
-70 & -116
\end{array}\right)
$$

[image]

**NOTE:** Both the vector spaces (domain and co-domain) have same basis **B** (given in the above image)

Now, if I consider a vector $$v = [1, 3] \in domain $$ then I get T(*v*) = [-19, 13].

Now,
$$
Av = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
724 \\
-418 
\end{array}\right)
$$

Clearly, we can see that, $$T(v) \neq Av$$

**MY QUESTION:**

How is the equation $$T(v) = Av$$ justified then? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know why folks are downvoting. Question is clear & I have also mentioned what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation matrix $A$ with respect to a basis $B$ tells you the coordinates in the basis $B$ of the images of the vectors of $B$. In order to get to the matrix $M$ that satisfies $T(v) = Mv$ you would have to find the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ because the coordinates of $(a,b)$ in this basis are simply $a$ and $b$.

For the given matrix $A$ the interpretation I mentioned means the following: To work with the matrix $A$ we have to turn our vector (in your example $v= (1,3)$) into its coordinates in the basis $B= \{(1,3), (2,5)\}$ that means: write $v = a \cdot (1,3) + b \cdot (2,5)$. It is clear that here $a=1, b=0$, so the coordinates of $v$ in the basis $B$ are $(1,0)$. We then calculate $A \cdot (1,0)^T = (121, -70)^T$. This result is the coordinates in $B$ of the desired vector $T(v)$. So we have to interpret the result as follows:
$$(121,-70) \overset{\wedge}{=} 121 \cdot (1,3) - 70 \cdot (2,5) = (-19, 13)$$

giving us the result that we expected.

So as you see you have to make a difference between usual vectors (which we often implicitely write down to mean the corresponding point in $\mathbb R^2$) and the interpretation of vectors as coordinates in a given basis. Hope this explanation helps you.